# Attend Church activity (Camp)

Tags: paperwork, b1-b2-visas, applications, camping

This is my first time applying for a B1/B2 visa, I am 26 year old and I have a regular job here in the Philippines. The airfare, food and accomodation during the camp, which is for 3 days, only will be covered by the Church. Do I have to present bank statements? Aside from that, what documents do I have to prepare aside from the invitation I received from California?

Comment: A trip from the Philippines to USA lasting just 3 days?

Comment: Yes, the sole purpose of going there is to attend the 3day camp.

Comment: Do you have a travel history, other ties to the Philippines apart from your job and a decent amount of savings? I don’t mean to be pessimistic but if not, your chances of getting a US visa on the premise of a 3 day trip paid for by a 3rd party are probably pretty slim.

Comment: I hesitate to raise this, but I wonder whether the perceived legitimacy of the church will have a bearing on the application's prospects.